# dynamic ip tracking with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip, tracking

I have a problem and I hope someone can help.

So I have a web page **(www.mydomain.com)**
And I have 3 partner. They are restaurants with wifi access.
If a guest connect to my web page through the wifi, I would show some offer.
It's easy, but I would like to show different offer to every restaurants.

I could use different domains, in every restaurants like:
www.mydomain.com/restaurant1
www.mydomain.com/restaurant2
www.mydomain.com/restaurant3

But I think more elegant the basic domain (www.mydomain.com) and some php code.

I tried to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  to know clinet IP. 
If I recognize the IP .I can show the right offer.
It is very helpful but my partners ip is not fix. They have dynamic ip.

My question is, how can I tracking my partners dynamic IP ?
Or What solutions exist to recognize who connected to my web page?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting geolocation or to simply track the IPs incoming?

Comment: To track the IP addresses of the businesses you would need to have a script inside the business that sends a ping to an API. With this API ping you just collect the `REMOTE_ADDR` and a unique ID for the business. Then you just store this and display offers if the user comes from one of this IP addresses. The other way is to manually get the IP addresses each day or whatever and update the database

Comment: Thanks guys!
@Machavity - Geolocation is a good idea. How can I do with php? If I try to check my location with my ip (http://whatismyipaddress.com/), That is not my location, that is show my ISP's location.

Comment: @mic - It is sounds good, but how can I use a script inside the business? They don't have any server, just a simple wifi router.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this strictly based on the IP and partially for the reasons you suggest. Namely that very few people have fixed IP addresses. Another factor is that, very soon (if you're not already), you're going to have to support IPv6 as well. Some ISPs will start using a public IPv6 and set the local address to a non-routing IP. That means that they might appear under the same IP. AOL used to do this many years ago and has now come full circle due to the IPv4 address shortage.

But I digress. It isn't a good idea either way. Even if you somehow got the IP thing working, it isn't easily scaled (what if you get 100 clients? 1000? How would you manage this?)

What you need to do is is give them some way to identify themselves. Maybe set up a login or a unique URL for them.